# Celery Periodic Tasks not running in Django

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

file structure

```
proj/proj/
         celery.py
         (and other files)
    /sitesettings/
         tasks.py
         (and other files)
```

celery.py

```
app = Celery('mooncake',broker_url = 'amqp://')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

sitesettings/tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from comma.models import Post
from mooncake.celery import app

app.conf.beat_schedule = {
'every-5-seconds': {
    'task': 'sitesettings.tasks.statisticsTag',
    'schedule': 5.0,
    'args': ()
},
}

@app.task
def statisticsTag():
    print(Post.objects.all()[0])
```

and run it with

```
celery -A proj beat -l info
```

it out put with

```
[2019-02-22 18:21:08,346: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task every-5-seconds (sitesettings.tasks.statisticsTag)
```

but no further output.
I used to try write it in proj/celery.py, but it cannot run cuz I have to import from another app, it exit with "app not loaded" error. So what should I do?

Comment: I believe that your task is being executed, but it's not printing what you want to print. For checking it you can change the task to do smth else, like change name or add some char to charfield every 5 seconds and see if it changed. What I suggest is to install Flower service and watch your tasks there: https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: It is not... cuz what I acturally do is calculate recent posts and save them as a global value. but it only has initial value.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The command you are calling to start celery `celery -A proj beat -l info` is [starting a beat scheduler instance](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#starting-the-scheduler) of celery which sends due tasks to a worker instance.

You will also need to [start a worker server](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#running-the-celery-worker-server) that will execute those due tasks. You can start a celery worker with the command `celery -A proj worker -l info`. This will need to be running **at the same time** as your scheduler is running.

Alternatively you can run a worker [with embedded beat scheduler](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.bin.worker.html#cmdoption-celery-worker-b) `celery -A proj worker -B -l info` but that is not recommended for production use.

Comment: There is a typo in the embedded beat scheduler command, it should be.
`celery -A proj worker -B -l info`

Comment: THANK YOU!! The docs for Celery 5 make it *shockingly unclear* that you now need to run TWO instances of celery to make scheduled tasks work.

Comment: This saves me lots of time, tks